# Allow pushing multiple heads without -f?

Tags: mercurial

For our project, we have two repositories: Main and Automated Testing. In the Testing repository, we allow multiple heads, so one commonly used "hg push -f" when pushing to the Testing repository. But using "push -f" is a bad habit, as one may accidentally use this for other repositories, too.

So I am looking for some configuration option, preferably on the repository side, which allows pushing multiple heads without using -f -- does Mercurial provide such an option?

(I know that I can install a hook to an repository to prevent it being the target of a forced push, but I would like to get rid of the need to use -f altogether.)

Comment: command alias for Testing repo?

Comment: This is a local solution for myself, but does not propagate badly to other developers.

Comment: Why do you allow multiple heads? You sure you don't want named branches?

Comment: Pretty sure, yes. The testing repository is nothing more than a convenient way to say "run tests on this revision" (but not on my machine). At least I even push revisions from a patch queue (mq) to it sometimes.

Comment: @cebewee - "this revision" can exist in any named branch

Comment: @cebewee - use [Projrc extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ProjrcExtension) for propagading alias

Comment: Can you provide a few details on how you make use of the multiple heads on anonymous branches in the testing repository?

Comment: @NickPierpoint I don't know the particularities of the testing system. There is a daemon which checks periodically whether there is a new, yet untested revision in the testing repository and checks it. We don't use any named branches, as, by project policy, we maintain a near linear history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution (unfortunately needed per-client) is to setup an alias in your `~/.hgrc` as follows:

```
[alias]
testboardpush = push -f ssh://example.com/testboard
```

You can then use `hg testboardpush` to push your commits to the automated testing repository, instead of getting into the bad habbit of using `push -f`.

If you have multiple repositories with multiple testboard locations, you can instead setup your alias  inside your `~/.hgrc` file as follows:

```
[alias]
testboardpush = push -f testboard
```

And then for each HG repository's `.hg/hgrc` file, have the lines:

```
[paths]
testboard = ssh://example.com/testboard
```

With this setup, typing `hg testboardpush` will always push to the correct place for the particular HG repository you are currently working in (or fail with an error if the path hasn't been setup).

Unfortunately, it does not appear you can do this from the server side without a custom version of HG; in particular, my reading of the `push` implementation in the [`localrepo.py` file of the HG sources](http://selenic.com/hg/file/a07be8953733/mercurial/localrepo.py#l1809) indicates it unconditionally checks for new heads using `discovery.checkheads` (and aborts) unless the `force` argument is set.